# Read a SwiftUI view's title set with `.navigationTitle(_ title:)`?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Does SwiftUI have a way to read the value  `.navigationTitle(_ title:)` sets?

Here is my code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Hello, world!")
    }.navigationTitle("Some title")
  }
}
```

```
let contentView = ContentView()
print(contentView.title) // Value of type 'ContentView' has no member 'title'
```

Comment: I've had a similar problem in the past (IDK which property it was specifically). When there was no reader defined, I made a workaround: I wrote a new view modifier (e.g. `queriableNavigationTitle`), which returns a custom `struct TitledView: View` with a `var navigationTitle: String`. In essence, I wrap the built-in view, and stash away a copy of the title for my own access later. It was gross, but IIRC it worked "fine"

Comment: This looks like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Try setting the title using a state variable or a computed property (or even as a `let` constant if it never changes). Then you can read the same variable or computed property elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @loremipsum I think that could mislead newbs. They’re completely normal structs, it’s just that they have private fields you can’t access, and have their concrete type usually hidden by opaque result types.

Comment: Fair point. The reason I'm raising this is because of how frequently "SwiftUI" is treated as some _alternative_ or v2 of "Swift", as if one isn't built on the other. The smoke and mirrors confuses people, and makes them think regular Swift rules somehow don't apply any longer. It's been a real source of confusion for beginners, from what I've seen

Comment: @loremipsum stop making things seem more complicated than they are please.

Comment: @loremipsum it's just a view modifier value placed on an opaque view that I'm trying to read.

Comment: @loremipsum your comment was not only misleading it is downright unhelpful.

Answer (score -1):

The [ViewInspector](https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector) framework can do this can do this and although it has many of the navigation properties, sadly it doesn't have `navigationTitle` yet ([availability list](https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector/blob/0.9.11/readiness.md)) but it would be something like:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
let title = try contentView.inspect().navigationTitle()
```

Here is the story behind it https://nalexn.github.io/swiftui-unit-testing/